# how to generate salary total sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have below tables called dailyshift,in 24 hours format

```
1 dailyshift
shiftid,employeeid,shiftdate        ,starttime    ,endtime hours
1        1           16th Aug 2019 ,  08:00         15:00   7
2        1           18th Aug 2019 ,  08:00         15:00   7
2        1           22th Aug 2019 ,  08:00         15:00   7
3        2           17th Aug 2019 ,  16:00         20:00  4

2 employeesalary

employeeid,salary, startdate      , enddate
 1         ,10,  , 1st Aug 2019  , 16th Aug 2019
 1         ,20,  , 17st Aug 2019 , 20th Aug 2019
 2         ,25,  , 15st Aug 2019 , 20th Aug 2019
```

we need to have ouptput week wise salary total like, we need to make total salary by employee per week ,according to their configured salary per hour.

```
empleeid      week               weektotal
  1         12th to 18th Aug       210
  1         19th to 25th Aug       140
  2         12th to 18th Aug       100
```

I have tried below but it is giving not accurate total

```
   select employeeid,sum(d.hours*salary) as weektotal from dailyshift as d
   inner join employeesalary as e
   on d.employeeid=e.employeeid
   group by employeeid
```

can we have way to make this?

Comment: You need to add the start and end date into your select and group by...

Answer (score 1):

Query may seems complex, but if you go through part by part, you will understand everything. CTE and CTE2 is just use for date manipulation to get the desired result.

```
 WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
     DATEADD(DAY, 1 - IIF(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(shiftdate,'st ','-'),'nd ','-'),'rd ','-'),'th ','-') AS DATETIME))-1 = 0,7,
            DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(shiftdate,'st ','-'),'nd ','-'),'rd ','-'),'th ','-') AS DATETIME))-1), 
        CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(shiftdate,'st ','-'),'nd ','-'),'rd ','-'),'th ','-') AS DATETIME)) [Week_Start_Date],
     DATEADD(DAY, 7 - IIF(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(shiftdate,'st ','-'),'nd ','-'),'rd ','-'),'th ','-') AS DATETIME))-1 = 0,7,
            DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(shiftdate,'st ','-'),'nd ','-'),'rd ','-'),'th ','-') AS DATETIME))-1),
        CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(shiftdate,'st ','-'),'nd ','-'),'rd ','-'),'th ','-') AS DATETIME)) [Week_End_Date]
     FROM dailyshift
 ),
 CTE2 AS(
    SELECT A.shiftid,A.employeeid,A.shiftdate,A.starttime,A.endtime,A.hours,
     CAST(DAY(Week_Start_Date) AS VARCHAR)+
     CASE
            WHEN DAY(Week_Start_Date) % 100 IN (11,12,13) THEN 'th ' --first checks for exception
            WHEN DAY(Week_Start_Date) % 10 = 1 THEN 'st '
            WHEN DAY(Week_Start_Date) % 10 = 2 THEN 'nd '
            WHEN DAY(Week_Start_Date) % 10 = 3 THEN 'rd '
            ELSE 'th ' --works for num % 10 IN (4,5,6,7,8,9,0)
        END
    +'To '+
    CAST(DAY(Week_End_Date) AS VARCHAR) +
     CASE
            WHEN DAY(Week_End_Date) % 100 IN (11,12,13) THEN 'th ' --first checks for exception
            WHEN DAY(Week_End_Date) % 10 = 1 THEN 'st '
            WHEN DAY(Week_End_Date) % 10 = 2 THEN 'nd '
            WHEN DAY(Week_End_Date) % 10 = 3 THEN 'rd '
            ELSE 'th ' --works for num % 10 IN (4,5,6,7,8,9,0)
        END +
    LEFT(DATENAME(Month,Week_End_Date),3) +' '+
    CAST(YEAR(Week_End_Date) AS VARCHAR) grp_clm_name
     FROM CTE A
 )

 SELECT A.employeeid,
 A.grp_clm_name Week,
 SUM(A.hours*B.salary) WeekTotal
 FROM CTE2 A
 INNER JOIN employeesalary B 
 ON A.employeeid = B.employeeid
 AND  CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(A.shiftdate,'st ','-'),'nd ','-'),'rd ','-'),'th ','-') AS DATETIME)
     BETWEEN  CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(B.startdate,'st ','-'),'nd ','-'),'rd ','-'),'th ','-') AS DATETIME)
     AND  CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(B.enddate,'st ','-'),'nd ','-'),'rd ','-'),'th ','-') AS DATETIME)
 GROUP BY A.employeeid, A.grp_clm_name
 ORDER BY 1
```

Output is-

```
employeeid  Week                    eekTotal
1           2th To 18th Aug 2019    210
2           12th To 18th Aug 2019   100
```

> Row with value "1 19th to 25th Aug 140" is missing as you have no salary definition for employee 1 for date 22th Aug 2019

Answer (score 0):

You need the applicable salary for the shift date so you need to do the following:

```
select d.employeeid, sum(d.hours * e.salary) as weektotal
from dailyshift as d
inner join employeesalary as e
on d.employeeid = e.employeeid
and d.shiftdate >= e.startdate 
and d.shiftdate <= e.endate
group by d.employeeid
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `EmployeeSalary` tables contains the hourly salary of employees, each employee can have different salary for different period.

Following query must give you expected result:

```
   select   employeeid, 
            DATEADD(day, -(DATEPART(dw, d.shiftdate)-1), d.shiftdate) [WeekStart],
            DATEADD(day, 7-(DATEPART(dw, d.shiftdate)), d.shiftdate) [WeekEnd],
            sum(d.hours*salary) as Weektotal 
   from     dailyshift as d
        inner join employeesalary as e
            on d.employeeid=e.employeeid and d.shiftdate between e.startdate and e.enddate
   group by employeeid, DATEADD(day, -(DATEPART(dw, d.shiftdate)-1), d.shiftdate), DATEADD(day, 7-(DATEPART(dw, d.shiftdate)), d.shiftdate)
```